# Adding a single space between each consecutive separators with SED

Tags: sed

This looked easy but it's messing with my head.

Convert this

```
"value:::text:::::othervalue:::::::text"
```

to this

```
"value: : :text: : : : :othervalue: : : : : : :text"
```

SED isn't recursive, so I get this:

```
$ echo "value:::text:::::othervalue:::::::text" | sed 's/::/: :/g'
> value: ::text: :: ::othervalue: :: :: ::text
```

Workaround, sed twice

```
$ echo "value:::text:::::othervalue:::::::text" | sed 's/::/: :/g;s/::/: :/g'
> value: : :text: : : : :othervalue: : : : : : :text
```

This doesn't look elegant, and it's not intuitive. Is there any command (in sed maybe?) that might do this more cleanly?

Thanks!

Note: I'm looking for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo '"value:::text:::::othervalue:::::::text"' | sed ':a;s/::/: :/g;ta'
```

Output:

```
"value: : :text: : : : :othervalue: : : : : : :text"
```

---

From sed man page:

> `t label`: If a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
>
> `: label`: Label for b and t commands.

Comment: NOTE: MAC & BSD version of sed requires label to be in a line by its own.

    echo "value:::text:::::othervalue:::::::text" | sed -e ':a' -e 's/::/: :/;t a'

Comment: @CarlosTroncoso Thank you for this hint.